# Adding the number of the position to an integer in a list

Tags: python

I need to add the number of the position of the integer in a list.

```
list=[10,10,10,10]
```

then the outcome should be

```
[10,11,12,13]
```

I know it works whit a loop but I dont know how. Thanks

Comment: An obnoxious way of doing it

    `>>> map(int.__add__, nums, range(len(nums)))`
    `[10, 11, 12, 13]`

Comment: this question shows _no_ effort or research.

Answer (score 2):

Get the index using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and add each element to it's index using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [10,10,10,10]
lst[:] = [i + ele for i,ele in enumerate(lst)]
print(lst)
[10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Which is the same as:

```
lst = [10, 10, 10, 10]

for i, ele in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i]  = i + ele
print(lst)
```

`i` is the `index` of each `element`, `ele` is each actual element in the list. The `lst[:]` syntax means we modify the original list and using the list comp is a more efficient version of the regular loop.